# How to deploy an existing Python package to JFrog local Artifactory?

Tags: python, artifactory, local

I am using local Artifactory, no remote. For in-house Python package deployment, I used `python setup.py bdist_wheel upload -r local`, it works.

I have installed **numpy** Python package through `pip install numpy`. I would like to re-deploy this package to local Artifactory.

For example, the installed path as follows:
`/<root>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy-1.21.6.dist-info/` which contains *INSTALLER*, *METADATA*, *RECORD*, *WHEEL*, *entry_points.txt*, and *top_level.txt*.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload any package to Artifactory using the following JFrog CLI command:

```
jf rt u path/to/local/package/file artifactory-repo-name
```

Before uploading the packages, make sure to configure your Artifactory connection details using the following command:

```
jf c add
```